# ImageButton is not visible after other layout is set to visible on real device

Tags: android, onclicklistener, visibility

I have an `ImageButton` which will be moved after it was clicked (onClickListener is implemented) and an `LinearLayout` which will be set to *visible* when the `ImageButton` clicked (also in its onClick method).

**Strange behaviour:** On my virtual device it works fine but on the real device the `ImageButton` is not visible again after the `LinearLayout` is set to *visible*. I also set the layout delayed (with a second) to *visible* and the `ImageButton` was moved correctly but as I said it is not *visible* again (also when I set it explicitly on VISIBLE) when the `LinearLayout` was set to *visible*)

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

The `onClickListener` implementation (I know hardcoded values are unresponsive but the App works only for one specific device):

```
private void setUpMenuBar() {
    final LinearLayout menuLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu_layout);

    menuLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    final int menuLayoutWidth = menuLayout.getWidth();
    final ImageButton openMenuBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_open_menu);
    openMenuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean menuVisible = false;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onClick", "menu visible: " + menuVisible + ", Rigth: " + openMenuBtn.getRight() + ", layoutWidth: " + menuLayoutWidth);
            if(menuVisible) {
                openMenuBtn.setRight(1920);
                openMenuBtn.setLeft(1720);
                menuLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                menuVisible = false;
            }
            else {
                openMenuBtn.setRight(1520);
                openMenuBtn.setLeft(1320);
                menuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                menuVisible = true;

            }
            Log.d("onClick", "menu visible: " + menuVisible + ", Rigth: " + openMenuBtn.getRight() + ", left: " + openMenuBtn.getLeft());
        }
    });
}
```

And the XML layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@mipmap/arrow"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/btn_open_menu"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/zahnrad"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_menu_settings"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/schraubendreher"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_menu_settings"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:src="@mipmap/fragezeichen"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_menu_settings_roundet"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said it works on virtual device but not on Real one.

You have set params of `setLeft()` and `setRight()` to huge values of 1920 and 1720 respectively. This might be pushing the ImageButton out of the screen of your real device depending upon pixels of the display your device packs.

Try with smaller values of paramaters to those methods and see, does it draw the views on display.

Answer (score 0):

Get Display Height and width using

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

then calculate setRight value and setLeft value from width and height